# Add an <h1> tag from filename on Linux

Tags: automation, html, find-and-replace

I have a folder with a bunch of html files and I wish to add an

`<h1>Filename without extension</h1>`

line just after the `<body>` tag.

How could I go about having a script or one-liner that would

1. Go through each file in the folder
2. Create the H1 tag based on the filename of the file but without the extension (example: file named `foobar.html` received an `<h1>foobar</h1>` line after the `<body>` line
3. Overwrite the files

?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? Are there some parameters in the `<body>` tag? Could you show some extracts of files and expected result?

Comment: Some body tags in some files contain other text, like lang= etc. The body tag appears once in each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small perl script that does the job:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Retrieve all html files in an array
my @files = glob '*.html';
# "slurp" mode
undef $/;
# loop over all files
for my $file(@files) {
    # open file in read mode
    open my $fhi, '<', $file or die "Can't open '$file' for reading: $!";
    # retrieve content in a single string
    my $content = <$fhi>;
    close $fhi;
    # remove extension
    (my $without_ext = $file) =~ s/\.[^.]+$//; #/this is a comment for syntaxic color!
    # add h1 tag with filename
    $content =~ s~<body[^>]*>~$&\n<h1>$without_ext</h1>~s;
    # open same file in write mode
    open my $fho, '>', $file or die "Can't open '$file' for writing: $!";
    # write the modified string in the file
    print $fho $content;
}
```

Comment: This would work one file at a time. I clarified my aim in the original question.

Comment: @ToDo: Sorry, it was just a test., See my edit, it works for all html files in a directory

Comment: Wouldn't this set the H1 line to "title"? I want to be identical to the filename without .html

Comment: @ToDo: Give me a minute :)

Comment: I saved the script in the same folder as the html files and ran it, but nothing seems to happen. The script exists immediately.

Comment: @ToDo: Do you have an error message? What is the result of `perl -v`? What is the ouput if you add `print "$_\n";` just after `for (@files) {`?

Comment: This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 2 (v5.26.2) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi. If I add `print "$_\n";` I get the list of the files in the folder.

Comment: @ToDo: It shoukd work. Are your files properly permissionned (read/write)? Change the open instruction like I did.

Comment: The script somewhat worked, but there are two issues. 1. Instead of adding an H1 after the BODY tag, the script copied all the text in the file and added a second copy at the end of the first with the H1 tag under the body tag. 2. The file extension is not removed (this is a minor issue I can workaround).

Comment: @ToDo:Sorry, I didn't test carefully. Now it works fine ;)